# Creating series of dialog boxes for parameter variables in sub-models of ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I'm working on a model to automatically generate ideal routes for mail delivery. The first thing it needs to do is ask the user whether he/she is doing a full route or a partial route. Then, it should go to one of two separate processes to either generate directions for a full route (based on the user putting in a single route number) or to generate directions for specific coded stops (entered individually by the user).

I have an if/then question at the beginning (Full Run or No) which asks the user whether they are doing a full route (Y or N). However, when I run this as one big model, the initial dialogue box includes the Full Run question (Y or N), a space for the user to enter the full route query, AND the a space for them to enter specific stops.

When I make full run and partial run sub-models, neither shows up in the dialogue box at all and the model runs but doesn't really do anything.

What I would like is a series of sequential dialogue boxes. The first one should ask "Full Run or Partial Run?" and the next one should EITHER be the run number request OR the multivalue stops request (based on whether the user picked Y or N). Anyone know of a way to do this? I know very little Python, so a pure ModelBuilder solution or just a conceptual explanation would be ideal

This is the main model:
[image: The main model with labels]

And this is what each of the two sub-models look like:
[image: Basic sub-model (of which there are two)]

Answer (score 1):

In the main model, right-click the sub-model and choose Make Variable > from parameter > [sub parameter name].

This will expose the sub-parameter model to the main model and you should now have it in the list of all the main model parameters.

Comment: OK, that is definitely helpful, but then is there a way to not have the "wrong" parameter show up? I have an "if" and two "then" scenarios and I only want the chosen "then" to show up in the dialogue as a parameter. I realize that means I need a 2nd dialogue to pop up after the user answers the "if" question and am just not sure if that's possible to do

Comment: @Ryan I think you're skirting the usefulness of Model Builder vs. creating a python script. To be honest, you should ping the ESRI GeoNet forum as (it's known) more ESRI Staff are on there than here...

Comment: Sounds good - will do